# What happens when regex matches overlap?

Tags: c++, regex, stl, c++11

In C++11 what happens if matches of a regex have intersections with each other? For example, if the source string is `"ababa"` and the regex is `"aba"`, first if I iterate on matches of the regex in string, are there two matches or only one? And next, if I replace all instances of `"aba"` with `"C"` using regex_replace, what will be the final result?

I cannot test that because I don't have access to a compiler that supports regex yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be one match, and the replacement result will be `Cba`.

Explanation:

- The regex engine starts at the first position in the string.
- It tries to match `aba` and succeeds.
- It replaces `aba` with `C` (result: `Cba`).
- It tries to match `aba` again from the current position (which is between `C` and `ba`).
- It fails here (and also from the next position (right before the final `a`) and the next (at the end of the string)).
- That's it.